# Factorial simplification rules

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to know if the following simplification that i did holds true

$$(2(n+1))! =  2(n+1)! = 2(n+1)(2n)!$$

and if not true what other simplification can work for it , it's a question about series that i am trying to solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equality does not hold true, since
$$(2(n+1))!=(2n+2)!=(2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)!$$
which is the correct (but probably already known) way to expand the given term.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try with $n=2$:
$$
(2(n+1))!=(2\times3)!=6!=720.
$$
$$
2(n+1)!=2\times 3!=12.
$$
$$
2(n+1)(2n)!=2\times3\times4!=144.
$$